# An event to be performed when I click a Panel in GWT/MGWT

Tags: gwt, mgwt

I want to perform an event when I click on a panel, in the same way this happens when the user clicks on a button.

I need this in order to handle events on click for this panel.

Comment: how is this a real question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use GWT [`FocusPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusPanel.html) which makes its contents focusable, and adds the ability to catch mouse and keyboard events. So wrap your `panel` inside `FocusPanel`.

```java
Panel panel = new Panel();    //Your panel here(ex;hPanel,vPanel)
FocusPanel focusPanel = new FocusPanel();

focusPanel.addClickListener(new ClickListener(){

    public void onClick(Widget sender) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

});

focusPanel.add(panel);
```

One more possibility(without FocusPanel)

```
 HorizontalPanel hpanel = new HorizontalPanel();
        hpanel.sinkEvents(Event.CLICK);
        hpanel.addHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }, ClickEvent.getType());
```

Comment: the code what you have given is not working..

Comment: Which panel you are using ?any exceptions ? use like this focusPanel.add(panel);  not panel.add(focusPanel).

Comment: As you said, I did a mistake, I wrote panel.add(focusPanel) instead of focusPanel.add(panel) .. now its working ..thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would make a new widget ( extending in this example an Absolute panel ) that implements the HasClickHandlers interface like this

```
public class MyCustomPanel extends AbsolutePanel
implements HasClickHandlers
{
    public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(
        ClickHandler handler)
    {
        return addDomHandler(handler, ClickEvent.getType());
    }
}
```

And then in my code I would do it like this

```
MyCustomPanel mPanel = new MyCustomPanel();
mPanel.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        // Do on click stuff here.
    }
});
```